# How to make an input mask for email?

Tags: angular, mask

To create a mask, I use [angular2 text mask](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2). I can't figure out how to make an input mask for email.

**Tried so:**

```
public emailMask = [/[a-z]/, '@',  /[a-z]/, '.', /[a-z]/ ]
```

But nothing works. Adds only two characters one in front of the other behind. How can I make an input mask for e-mail (Other tools for masking on the angular 2+ are welcome).

Comment: To use Text mask for Email Refer this example - https://text-mask.github.io/text-mask/ which will guide you. To mask email you have to use email mask [Addon](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/addons#emailmask) and use it in your application [this way](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/addons#emailmask)

Comment: Please refer this library. It does all for you https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/inputmask. If you are not willing to import the library, then you can refer to the source code

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the following packages:

```
npm install --save angular2-text-mask
npm install --save text-mask-addons
```

After you need to add `TextMaskModule` to your `{name}.module.ts`:

For example (app.module.ts):

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TextMaskModule } from 'angular2-text-mask';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    TextMaskModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then add to input `textMask` to `{name}.component.html`:

For example (app.component.html):

```
<input [textMask]="{mask: emailMask}" placeholder="example@domain.com">
```

After that add `emailMask` to `{name}.component.ts`:

For example (app.component.ts):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import emailMask from 'text-mask-addons/dist/emailMask';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  emailMask = emailMask;
}
```

Comment: Does this support different language email? ÀÁÂÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÙÚÛÜÝ@test.com